# jne to value in eax

Tags: assembly, x86

For a class I need to do a conditional jump to the value $0x55683af8:
However this code is not valid. How i can jump to the following value?

```
 mov    $0x55683af8,%eax
 cmpl   $0xdeadbeef,0x0(%ebp)
 jne    *%eax
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use conditional jumps in combination with register, instead that you can do...

```
 mov    $0x55683af8,%eax
 cmpl   $0xdeadbeef,0x0(%ebp)
 je     Skip 
 jmp    *%eax        //or call
Skip
```

Comment: This looks great, unfortunately I get the following error for line 3 
`je Skip:`
`Error: junk ':' after expression`

Comment: Sorry I'm normally using NASM assembler. Fixed. :)